# What is the correct percent difference formula?

Tags: percentages

While googling for `percent difference formulas`,  I got two different formulas:

> 1. (difference/old-value)$\times 100$.
> 2. (difference/average)$\times 100$.

So, for $6$ and $9$, the first one gives $-33$ and the second gives $-40$. Which one is correct and when is either formula used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

If you start out with $6$ and then it increases to $9$, and you want to know by how much the original value *increased* (or *decreased*), then you use **[(new value - old value)/old value] * 100.  So, here, it would be $\dfrac{9 - 6}{6}*100 = \dfrac{3}{6}*100 = 50$%.  (If when using this formula, your percent is a negative number, then that is the percentage it decreased by.

Answer (score 1):

`(difference/old-value)×100` is the most commonly used formula, but isn't ideal for all situations.

`(x-y/f(x,y))×100` is the generic percent difference formula, and what you put for `f(x,y)` could vary depending on your goals.  This is especially of concern if you're dealing with negative numbers or doing further math on the percentages.

> Several common choices for the function f(x, y) would be:
>
> max(|x|, |y|),
>
> max(x, y),
>
> min(|x|, |y|),
>
> min (x, y),
>
> (x + y)/2, and
>
> (|x| + |y|)/2.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference
- [How to calculate the percentage of increase/decrease with negative numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716767/how-to-calculate-the-percentage-of-increase-decrease-with-negative-numbers/942665#942665)