# Percent variance - negative and positive numbers

Tags: percentages

I need to calculate the percent variance between a negative and positive number and am not sure how to do it.  The numbers are $-45000000$  and $8500000$. Normally when I look at percent variance I would do the following, $\frac{8500000}{-45000000}-1$.

Comment: Related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716767/how-to-calculate-the-percentage-of-increase-decrease-with-negative-numbers